# os x python script not reading /Users/myname/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc

Tags: python, matplotlib

Running the script below in Terminal points to

```
import matplotlib
print(matplotlib.matplotlib_fname())
```

/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc

but running it in TextMate I get

/Users/myname/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc

What's controlling which matplotlibrc is used and how do I control it?

I installed the python-2.7 using brew.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I needed to put

```
export MPLCONFIGDIR=$HOME/.matplotlib
```

somewhere that would be read by running ~/.profile (e.g. in ~/.profile).

I don't know why it is not found automatically.